Unable to setup explicit IP list to target pools in GCP
Since the cost of building a Load Balancer cluster is too high, I want to directly set up a Network Load Balancer on GCP and forward the traffic directed to this Load Balancer to a specified IP Address List (my services with public ips), similar to the effect of HAProxy. However, after going through the documentation, I couldn't find how to set IP Addresses in Target Pools.
For example:
frontend http_front
    bind *:80
    default_backend http_back

backend http_back
    balance roundrobin
    server server1 11.22.33.1:80 check
    server server2 11.22.33.2:80 check
    server server3 11.22.33.3:80 check

I'm new to GCP, I am quite confused why can't GCP do this...
Is this functionality prohibited by GCP? Can anyone help answer this question?

Your question is unclear, lacks references and code. The documentation for instances in target-pools is clear. Instances are referenced by unique Instance URLs.
